# checking whether a field exists in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Consider this snippet of Jade:

```
if(#{episode[question.name][field]})
   #{episode[question.name][field]}
```

I  want to check if the value of `episode[question.name][field]` exists. If it does, output the value on the next line.

> 500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Here is the current source and more information.

```
h1= title
```

p Welcome to #{title}

```
ol#questions
    each question in questions
        li  
            ul#question
                li: h3  (#{question.name})  #{question.description}
                - if(question.options)
                    ul#options
                        for option, i in question.options
                            if(typeof(option) === "object")
                                li: h3  #{i}
                                ul#option
                                        each soption in option
                                            li
                                                input(type='checkbox',  name='episode[#{question.name}][#{soption}]',   checked='#{episode[question.name][soption]}')
                                                //
                                                label
                                                    #{soption}  
                            else
                                li
                                    input(type='checkbox',  name='episode[#{question.name}][#{option}]',    checked='#{episode[question.name][option]}')
                                    //
                                    label
                                        #{option}
                if(typeof(question.fields) !== 'undefined')
                    for field, i in question.fields
                        if(field === "Date")
                            p.date
                                if(#{episode[question.name][field]} !== "undefined")                    
                                    #{episode[question.name][field]}
                        else
                            p                       
                                input(name='episode[#{question.name}][#{field}]', class='', value="#{episode[question.name][field]}")
```

and here is the data object passed in

```
 episode =   {
  "form": {
    "formid": "4efd9c4cae999dcf0a12c461",
    "name": "ROC"
  },
  "patientid": ObjectId("4ef6835a7a5869082a80bc95"),
  "certperiodid": ObjectId("4f020ff0850b21bc2b000001"),
  "M0080": {
    "2-PT": "on",
    "3-SLP\/ST": "on",
    "4-OT": "on"
  },
  "M0090": {
    "Date": "2012-01-02"
  },
  "M0100": {
    "1 - Start of care--further visits planned": "on",
    "3 - Resumption of care (after inpatient stay)": "on"
  },
  "M00104": {
    "Date": "2012-05-02"
  },
  "_id": ObjectId("4f071a0424ddf0dd66000003")
}
```

How can this be fixed and written correctly?

so for example if one of the date fields are empty (not filled in), in order to prevent an error , i need to check if its not empty, before outputting the value.

thanks again in advance

Comment: Does your actual code have the `- ` in front of the `if`?

Comment: no it dosent, but i will try that now.

Comment: (Also, you are giving multiple DOM elements the same id (`questions`) in the question list; that's invalid HTML--consider using a class instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions shouldn't use escaping:

```
- if (episode[question.name][field])
  foo
```

(Assuming proper variable setup, obviously.)

---

*Edit to respond to comment*

You're not checking to see if the element exists first before trying to read the field, in both the date display and the input element... While your usecase is a bit opaque still, you need to check for the element first:

```
- if (episode[question.name] && episode[question.name][field])",
```

I *think* you're trying to show an input element for things without values, and display it otherwise--not quite sure. You may want something closer to this (w/o knowing what you're doing, I made a fake template w/ what I think mirrors your data--I commented the `"2-PT"` value out to test). Some minor refactoring to clean things up, but not much.

```
var s = [
  "ol#questions",
  "  each question in questions",
  "    li",
  "      ul.question",
  "        li: h3  (#{question.name})  #{question.description}",
  "        if question.fields",
  "          each field, i in question.fields",
  "            - var foo = field === 'Date' ? 'date' : ''",
  "            p(class='#{foo}')",
  "              if episode[question.name]",
  "                - var field_value = episode[question.name][field] || '' ",
  "                if field_value",
  "                  #{field_value}",
  "                else",
  "                  input(name='episode[#{question.name}][#{field}]', class='', value='#{field_value}')",
  ""
].join("\n");

var locals = {
  "question": {
    "name": "M00104"
  },
  "episode": {
    "M00104": {
      // "2-PT": "on",
      "Date": "2012-01-02"
    }
  },
  "questions": [
    {
      "name": "M00104",
      "description": "Do we have it?",
      "fields": ["Date", "2-PT"]
    },
  ]
}

var jade = require('jade');
var fn = jade.compile(s);
console.log(fn(locals));
```

After tidying:

```
<ol id="questions">
  <li>
    <ul class="question">
      <li>
        <h3>(M00104) Do we have it?</h3>
      </li>

      <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
        <p class="date">2012-01-02</p>

        <p class="">on</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

With the `"2-PT"` line commented out:

```
<p class=""><input name="episode[M00104][2-PT]" value="" class=""></p>
```

Comment: Well you see the problem is for example "quesion.name" the generated value, is the name to be used to get the value from the episode object. I dont know if i explained that right. "question.name" as it is,(is a property of a question object). the value of question.name is what i am using to refer to the value i want from the episodes object.

Comment: @mojotaker Right; I understand that. Expressions should be just that--raw JavaScript expressions. If you're passing in `question`, the syntax I'm showing is what you should use. (And `field`.)

Comment: When you're referencing a value outside of an expression that's when you need the `#{}`.

Comment: Thank you. using your suggestion, i dont get any syntax errors anymore. Thank you. But the purpose of the if statement was to prevent an error if one of the date fields were empty. I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'Date' of undefined" error.

Comment: @mojotaker Then your logic and/or data is incorrect; what does a `question` look like? Where exactly do you get it?

Comment: @mojotaker The `if` statement still has the `#` in it, and you're not checking for `typeof` in that `if` as in your previous one. You should just use JS's truthy/falsey, though, and not bother with the strict `===`, IMO, but it's hard to know what exactly you're doing still.

Comment: Wow wow wow wow wow. Thank you thank you thank you. let me look over your reply.